# Animate draw to canvas in drawable

Tags: android, animation, canvas, android-drawable

I have a drawable that draws a progress bar using `onLevelChange` and calls `draw()` to make a line at bottom on canvas. How can I animate this line draw?

```
public class BorderProgressDrawable extends Drawable {

    private static final int MAX_LEVEL = 10000;

    private int mLevel = 0;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public BorderProgressDrawable(Context context) {
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth((float) CommonMethods.dpToPx(context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(), 4));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        int height = canvas.getHeight();
        float visibleWidth = (((float) mLevel) / MAX_LEVEL) * width;
        canvas.drawLine(0, height, visibleWidth, height, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int i) {
        mPaint.setAlpha(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
        if (colorFilter != null) mPaint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return mPaint.getAlpha();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onLevelChange(int level) {
        mLevel = level;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: animate? animate what?

Comment: The line drawn, currently if progress goes from progress 0 to 5000, you'll see that line suddenly drawn to that level, I want to animate this draw, so its drawn in, maybe like 100 ms. Makes sense?

Comment: i have no idea what you want to achieve... what 100 ms?

Comment: i know what ms means, i dont know what you want to animate, do you want to use ValueAnimator or something?

Comment: I don't know what ValueAnimator is. I want to animate what is done by this line `canvas.drawLine(0, height, visibleWidth, height, mPaint);`, Can you give me an example of using ValueAnimator with canvas?

Comment: first of add `Log.d` statements inside `onLevelChange` and `draw`, what do you see then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89892/discussion-between-sourabh-and-pskink).